# Why is my google maps search one instance behind?

Tags: google-maps, flutter

Currently I'm developing a flutter widget where a user can set his/her home location. This can be done by typing his/her address or localizing him/herself.
Right now I got almost everything to work, the user can localize himself and then his/her address will show up in a box and the map will move to that location.
Except when the user types a location my widget is one instance behind; When the user searches first for New York, nothing will happen. If the user then continues to search for Amsterdam, the map and text jump to the previous searched location: New York.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance,
Kind regards!

My code:

```
const kGoogleApiKey = "API KEY HERE";

// Also set API Key in androidmanifest.xml

GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);

class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  LocationScreenState createState() {
    return LocationScreenState();
  }
}

class LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
  GoogleMapController googleMapController;
  bool myLocation = false;
  var lat;
  var lng;
  String addressline;
  String geoaddressline;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

    Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
    if (p != null) {
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
      await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);

      lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
      lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;

      final coordinates = Coordinates(lat, lng);
      var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
      var first = addresses.first;
      addressline = "${first.addressLine}";
   }
  }

    @override build(BuildContext context){
      return
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              googleMapController = controller;
                },
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(0.0, 0.0), // or other default location
              zoom: 7
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(top:40, height:80, left:20, right:20, 
            child:
              Container( 
                color: Colors.white,
                  child:
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child:
                          GestureDetector(onTap: () async {
                            myLocation = false;
                            Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                            context: context, apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);
                            displayPrediction(p);
                            googleMapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: 19)));
                            googleMapController.clearMarkers();
                            googleMapController.addMarker(MarkerOptions(infoWindowText: InfoWindowText('Home','Here do I live!'),draggable: false, consumeTapEvents: false, position: LatLng(lat, lng)));
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                        child: 
                          Center(
                            child: 
                              Text(
                                addressline == null && geoaddressline == null ? 'Search Location' :
                                addressline == null && geoaddressline != null ? geoaddressline :
                                addressline != null && geoaddressline == null ? addressline :
                                addressline != null && geoaddressline != null && myLocation == true ? geoaddressline : addressline

                                , style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),),),
                          ), 
                      ),
                        IconButton(
                          iconSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          icon: Icon(Icons.my_location),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            myLocation = true;
                            Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
                            googleMapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude), zoom: 19)));
                            googleMapController.clearMarkers();
                            googleMapController.addMarker(MarkerOptions(infoWindowText: InfoWindowText('Home', 'Here do I live'),draggable: false ,consumeTapEvents: false, position: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude)));
                            var geoaddress = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(Coordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude));
                            var first = geoaddress.first;
                            geoaddressline = "${first.addressLine}";
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                        ),
                    ],),
                  ),
              ),
    ],); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try setting up map controller outside the build function like below?

```
_onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
  googleMapController = controller;
}
```

You can than pass it to GoogleMap

```
GoogleMap(
  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated
)
```

Update:

It appears like displayPrediction(p) is an async function and you are not waiting for it to finish before calling setState. Can you add await before calling displayPrediction(p);

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with the onMapCreated argument of GoogleMap. I think the problem with my LatLngs or map movement code.

Comment: It appears like displayPrediction(p) is an async function and you are not waiting for it to finish before calling setState. Can you add await before calling displayPrediction(p);